# The value 'Xrm.XrmServiceContext, Xrm' is not recognized as a valid type or is not of the type 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceContext'

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to connect to MS Dynamics 2011 Online. On the using xrm part of my code, I receive this error:

**The value 'Xrm.XrmServiceContext, Xrm' is not recognized as a valid type or is not of the type 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceContext'.**

Here is my code:

```cs
        var contextName = "Xrm";
        using (var xrm = CrmConfigurationManager.CreateContext(contextName) as XrmServiceContext)
        {


            WriteExampleContacts(xrm);

            //Create a new contact called Allison Brown.
            var allisonBrown = new Xrm.Contact
            {
                FirstName = "Allison",
                LastName = "Brown",
                Address1_Line1 = "23 Market St.",
                Address1_City = "Sammamish",
                Address1_StateOrProvince = "MT",
                Address1_PostalCode = "99999",
                Telephone1 = "12345678",
                EMailAddress1 = "allison.brown@example.com"
            };

            xrm.AddObject(allisonBrown);
            xrm.SaveChanges();

            WriteExampleContacts(xrm);
        }
```

App.config:

```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  <section name="microsoft.xrm.client" type="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Configuration.CrmSection, Microsoft.Xrm.Client"/>
  </configSections>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Xrm"     
connectionString="Url=https://MYORG.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices"/>
  </connectionStrings>

<microsoft.xrm.client>
<contexts>
  <add name="Xrm" type="Xrm.XrmServiceContext, Xrm"/>
</contexts>
</microsoft.xrm.client>
</configuration>
```

Xrm.XrmServiceContext is my actual XrmServiceContext name. It is held in Xrm.cs file in my console application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the simplified connection.

You need to refer `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client` and `Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Services`

```cs
CrmConnection crmConnection = CrmConnection.Parse("Url=https://XXX.crm4.dynamics.com; Username=user@domain.onmicrosoft.com; Password=passwordhere; DeviceID=contoso-ba9f6b7b2e6d; DevicePassword=passcode;");
OrganizationService service = new OrganizationService(crmConnection);

XrmServiceContext context = new XrmServiceContext(service);

var allisonBrown = new Xrm.Contact
            {
                FirstName = "Allison",
                LastName = "Brown",
                Address1_Line1 = "23 Market St.",
                Address1_City = "Sammamish",
                Address1_StateOrProvince = "MT",
                Address1_PostalCode = "99999",
                Telephone1 = "12345678",
                EMailAddress1 = "allison.brown@example.com"
            };

context.AddObject(allisonBrown);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't need the 4 in crm4 because I'm using the online edition.

Comment: crm, crm4 or crm5 depends in which area (US, EMEA, APAC) is hosted your crm online environment.

Comment: Where can I find Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Services ?

Comment: @AllWorkNoPlay the DLLs are inside the Dynamics CRM SDK. Select your version from here: http://www.crmanswers.net/p/resources-for-crm-developers.html

Comment: regarding `Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Services`you need to do `using Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Services;` in the top of your code

Comment: While this works around the issue.  It's not using CrmConfigurationManager and the configuration advantages it can bring around making your CrmService threadsafe, and additional caching.
http://develop1.net/public/post/Microsoft-Xrm-Client-(Part-3b)-Configuration-via-appwebconfig.aspx